# Programmatic alternative to @Cacheable annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

Recently I have been dabling in architecture, and I have a use-case where a very expensive computation from my domain is called very often with same parameters ( before you jump to any conclusions, I do not determine the parameters, and these are completely provided by external callers ). I would like to keep my application architecture as clean as possible and would not like to add a dependency on Spring in my domain layer, but I would still like to use Spring caching capabilities.

I am aware that Spring provides `@Cacheable` annotation, but as said I do not want to use those on my classes to avoid adding a dependency on Spring.

Is it possible to do something like:

```java
@Configuration
public MyConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    public DomainClass createDomainClassBean() {
        DomainClass domainInstance = new DomainClass(...);
        // Programatically add @Cacheable annotation to the domain class.
        ...
    }

}
```

Is it possible to enable `@Cacheable` behavior for methods programatically, without relying on the annotation?

Edit: I am open to alternatives, which do not rely on Spring capabilities, but I would prefer avoiding adding dependencies to domain layer.

Comment: Do you use spring at all in your application? If so: At some point your domain layer get's invoked from 'outside'. So why not using a wrapper class which invokes the domain class but with `@Cachable` on the method?

Comment: So you want all of the normal Spring Cache behavior, just without putting the annotation on your domain class? Also, in your example `createDomainClassBean()` is a singleton. Would you use the prototype scope in the real implementation? Will it always be a Spring Bean?

Comment: @DanielWosch Yes I do use Spring in my application, but none of the domain classes or application-layer classes have Spring annotations applied to them, to keep them decoupled from Spring. All of the wiring is done with `@Configuration` and `@Bean` ( yes I know this is dogmatic and has overhead, but this application is more of an architectural training ground and exploring what is possible and what not). I can not use a wrapper class, since "domain class" is used by "use case" class, and the "use-case" class can not depend on externalities as well ( hexagonal architecture )

Comment: @DanielWosch Your proposal gave the following idea. I could extend the `DomainClass` in the upper-most layer of my application, and then basically forward all calls to super, while adding `@Cacheable` where necessary. That way I would be able to keep the technical details outside of the domain.

Comment: @Knox yes you are right I want to have the cake and to eat it too. Yes the bean is a singleton. I do not have a plan to use it as a prototype bean and yes it will always be a Spring bean ( but I am open to alternatives ).

Comment: @TheCoolDrop Okay cool. I have also build some sample applications based on the hex-arch so I know your struggle ;). At some point you are working outside of your domain e.g. your WebAdapter which uses a certain UseCase interface. So the webadapter could provide a `@Cachable` method which calls the UseCase -> domain class. Or are the adapter / application / Infrastructure layers also free from spring related annotations?

Comment: Well I putting `@Cacheable` on adapter would probably be acceptable solution, the thing is that expensive domain computation is being also consumed in multiple "domain services", which orchestrate multiple domain entities, so adapter is not the only entry point for expensive domain computation. In the end it must actually be cacheable on domain level, and not on some higher level. But good idea, and it is always nice to see that other people care about similar concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Spring's [`CacheProxyFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheProxyFactoryBean.html) class.

Internally, Spring's [Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) and caching infrastructure applied to Spring application service classes, your application domain classes, (whether using [Declarative, Annotation-based Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations) configuration and demarcation, or [Declarative, XML-based Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-declarative-xml) configuration, etc) is all [backed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable) by [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop).  After all, applying caching capabilities to application service components is a form of *decoration*.

The `CacheProxyFactoryBean` [accepts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheProxyFactoryBean.html#setCacheOperationSources-org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationSource...-) an array of [`CacheOperationSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheOperationSource.html) objects used to [identify](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheOperationSource.html#getCacheOperations-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Class-) the type of [cache operation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheOperation.html)(s) (e.g. GET/PUT, EVICT, etc; for example, the [CacheableOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheableOperation.html) for the `@Cacheable` annotation) to perform on the proxy target's methods which are [identified](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheProxyFactoryBean.html#setPointcut-org.springframework.aop.Pointcut-) by an AOP Pointcut.

As you know, [one source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/AnnotationCacheOperationSource.html) of caching configuration (metadata) for a cache enabled operation applied to (demarcating) your application service method is from an Annotation, like Spring's `@Cacheable` annotation, not unlike how you'd use Spring's Transaction Management (with `@Transactional`) or Spring Security.

Obviously, there are sources to parse (per) cache (operation) configuration from XML.

These are the infrastructure classes that Spring's caching infrastructure is essentially using under-the-hood when using Annotation or XML configuration to proxy your application service components and apply caching behavior.

You can manually set all of this up yourself (using Java-based configuration) to minimize the Spring footprint in your application classes, but that is quite a bit of boilerplate just to avoid Spring types in your application [service | DAO/Repository] classes when in fact Spring is already a dependency of your application.

It is somewhat akin to using JPA Annotations for application domain model classes (or entities), but that is in fact far worse given JPA Annotations are present in your domain "model" classes, IMO.

Alternatively, you could use XML (rather than Java-based configuration) or use JSR-107 Cache Annotations, which are [supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-jsr-107) by Spring as well.

Food for thought.

Comment: NOTE: You can mix (a bit of) XML configuration (perhaps, just for caching) with Java-based configuration in Spring.  See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-combining

Comment: This is very detailed answer. Thank you for posting this, I will expolore the attached resources and hopefully reach my goal.

Comment: Additional note, Spring AOP works through proxies by default. That means that caching happens in the proxy, and not your domain class itself. That's why I was asking about keeping these as beans- everywhere you want caching, use must use the Spring-created bean (the proxy). That means you can't deserialize domain from JSON, load it directly from the database, etc, and still have the caching work.

Comment: I suppose the `DomainClass` in your example above is a bit ambiguous.  If it is a "model" (data) class (e.g. Customer) in your application domain, then adding caching there is a bit unusual as would be making it a bean that would be managed by Spring.  I took your domain class to mean a `@Service` class or `@Repository` (DAO), where crossing cutting concerns like caching, or security, transaction management and so on would typically be managed.

Comment: It is true that Spring uses proxies for AOP by default.  AOP is a form of decoration after all exactly like the Decorator design pattern.  It is meant to enhance the functionality of you domain class in some way (i.e. caching, security, etc).  But stranger things have happened and If your domain model classes (serialized to and from the database as JSON) typically requires caching then you really only have 2 approaches: ...

Comment: First, is to programmatically use the Spring's Caching API (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/package-summary.html) directly in your model class(es), which then unduly couples you to Spring.  The primary interfaces in this cases are the `CacheManager` and `Cache`, but probably only the `Cache` interface would be needed in your case.

Comment: The second approach would involve using Spring AOP Load-Time Weaving (LTW; See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj and more specifically, here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-aj-ltw).  This uses the AspectJ compiler to actually modify the byte code of your application domain * class.  The result is a AspectJ proxy and not a Spring JDK Proxy (which is what Spring creates by default)...

Comment: Since serialization in any format (JSON or otherwise) only stores the "data" of your domain model class, then when the data is deserialized, it will be deserialized into an instance of the AspectJ proxy of your domain model class, where caching logic has been "woven" into the class definition.

Comment: While this should be possible: 1) I have not tried it, and 2) I would personally not recommend it, either.  As I stated above, concerns like caching, logging, security, transactions, etc are a cross-cutting concern and should be applied to the Service or DAO components of your application that are typically managed as beans by Spring.  Hopefully, I am understanding you correctly and you find this helps, or at least gives you other ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: @JohnBlum I love your enthusiasm and fact that you kept checking on. Thank you very much for that. So to answer some of your question now. Yes DomainClass is something that would normally be `@Service`, but since I am working with hexagonal architecture the Spring dependency is not allowed. This brings us directly to your second concern of deeply coupling myself to Spring. That exactly what I am trying to avoid, by avoiding having all of the Spring annotations in my domain services. Goal is to be able to reuse the domain in other frameworks or deployment styles

Comment: For example once the application is built and my domain is decoupled from Spring I am free to deploy my domain code using Lambda functions or some other framework, while being decoupled from Spring. Admittedly I would be having to give up on some technical capabilities like caching, but the functionality of my application would remain unchanged.

I understand your concern with respect to JSON serialization, but this is not relevant or my case, since this is more like `@Service`-type of class rather than a value object or data container.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop - You are welcome. Regarding your application architecture and fully decoupling your application from any framework, such as Spring, this is also why I suggested externalizing the configuration of your application (perhaps only caching) using Spring XML.  You can still proxy service (or alternatively DAO/Repository) components with XML config. Then, in no way would your application domain classes actually have any dependency (e.g. imports) on Spring types.

Comment: Even if you used Spring Java configuration, that configuration could be modularized and compiled/packaged based on whether your application will use Spring at runtime, I suppose.

Comment: As I also stated, alternatively, you could rely on JSR-107, JCache annotations, which are supported by Spring and would have no effect when caching is not enabled.  Therefore, your dependency would only be on Java, or rather Java extensions itself (i.e. the JCache API).  The presence of caching annotations implies a service is cacheable, but not necessarily will things be cached, which is fine since decoration does not alter the contract, only the behavior.

Comment: Finally, and admittedly, I am still a bit confused about how JSON serialization plays into all of this. I get the hexagonal architecture, but if the application service classes are in some way serialized, then I guess that is beyond me.  Of course, as I stated, there is AspectJ, if that helps.  Additionally, you could add an additional layer of indirection by providing your own Caching SPI (similar) to Spring (or JCache) and plug-in different caching providers as needed/available.  Keep in mind that Spring's Cache Abstraction is simply an SPI itself; it is not an implementation.